# Firebase signInWithPopup function closes immediately in nextjs project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication

I'm using the signInWithPopup function to sign in. It works in the development stage (local server).

```
  const firebaseAuth = getAuth(app);
  const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
  const [{ user, cartShow, cartItems }, dispatch] = useStateValue();

  const [isMenu, setIsMenu] = useState(false);

  const login = async () => {
    if (!user) {
      const {
        user: { refreshToken, providerData },
      } = await signInWithPopup(firebaseAuth, provider);
      dispatch({
        type: actionType.SET_USER,
        user: providerData[0],
      });
      localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(providerData[0]));
    } else {
      setIsMenu(!isMenu);
    }
  };
```

I uploaded my project to Vercel. I tried using different browsers such as Chrome, Edge, Opera. Also, I gave permission for 'Pop-ups and redirects'. But it didn't work. The popup window closes shortly after I call it.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed my error. I should have added my domain to the Authorised Domains located in firebase auth settings.